# How to get root ViewGroup from a layout that was set using setContentView?

Tags: android

I cannot seem to find a way to get this ViewGroup. Not sure if there are any standard ways to get ViewGroups.

What I want to accomplish is to dynamically add a full screen overlay view to any Layout at run time, and in order to do this, I always need to get the root ViewGroup.  Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: If you have the View of the layout, would view.getParent() work?

Comment: You gave the ViewGroup an id in the layout file right?

Answer (score 46):

Try using

```
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Every layout has this ViewGroup as parent.

Comment: Also a great way to get https://github.com/jinatonic/confetti up and running quickly

Comment: This cast will never fail?

Answer (score 8):

```
getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

set this view directly

Answer (score 3):

Works for me

```
getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
```

Comment: I was able to use this by adding a ViewGroup cast.