# Android/Java - Combinding custom SurfaceView and XML Layout?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, surfaceview

I am making a simple game as a project that is basically a simple version of Galaga with some modifications. I am very new to android and Java (primarily a C++ person) so at first I just made the ship automatically move right and holding down on the screen makes the ship move left. I did this to keep it simple (as it was easy to implement an on-touch listener within my GameView for this task) so that I could finish the rest of the basic framework of the app before going back and improving the functionality of particular bits.

Right now my GameView is created programmatically within GameActivity and then "setContentView()" is used to set the activity's view to the new GameView:

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private GameView gameView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    gameView = new GameView(this, size.x, size.y);
    setContentView(gameView);
}
```

Now what I want, is two small buttons in the corner of the screen that move the ship left and right, but I am stuck on how to easily do this because each way I keep thinking of gets really complicated (mostly due to being an android novice).

The two best ways I can think of are as follows:

1) Use the Android Studio XML design tool to place the buttons and my custom SurfaceView (GameView) into the proper locations and then just use "setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)" within my GameActivity.

This would be great; however, there's two problems I cannot figure out how to overcome. First, when I drag "view" into the layout for GameActivity and select my custom SurfaceView "GameView" in the pop-up window, I get an error:

[image]

and additionally, as you can see in the code I posted, a GameView needs to be passed two integers whenever it is created and I don't see how I could make this happen if I just put a GameView in my XML layout with the designer.

2) Continue creating the GameView programmatically like I am, setup the GameActivity layout using the designer to contain all the buttons I need, then programmatically add the GameView (custom SurfaceView) to the GameActivity layout before finally using "setContentView(R.layout.activity_game)". This seems the most simple to me, but I don't know how to grab a reference to the entire XML layout that's created with the activity by default (activity_game.xml) and then add the created GameView to it. I can only find code examples for using "findViewById()" to reference pieces of an XML made layout (like a button, or linear layout within the XML made layout). I imagine I might be able to create a Frame layout or something similar within the XML designer and then attach everything to that and use "findViewById()" to attach my GameView to the frame, but I don't know if that would work. Finally, I have a feeling that because the buttons on the XML layout would have existed first, programmatically adding the GameView would mean that the buttons would get covered up and I don't know how to avoid that.

Sorry for the long-winded question but I just couldn't find any sample code or previous questions/answers that addressed this specifically, I could only find bits and pieces that I wasn't sure how to put together.

Any help on the easiest way to have my buttons created in "activity_game.xml" appear on-top of my programmatically created GameView so I can easily position the buttons and easily grab them by ID for on-click listeners?

EDIT:

As requested this is the current setup for activity_game.xml, the frame layout is just there as part of my experimentation but is not actually being used right now since the content view for the activity is set to GameView. I have the button just floating there because right now I am just trying to get it to show up and will worry about proper implementation once I reach that point:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_game"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.chrisheimlich.galaticrenegade.GameActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/testFrame"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="113dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Fun stuff, if you're looking to create a view that can be displayed in Android Studio layout editor, you need to ensure that the view overrides a constructor.  Have you taken a look at the [documentation on custom views](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html)

Comment: For method 2, you could get a reference to the *root view group* and programmatically add your custom view.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/24612529/3166366.  Could your post the xml for the `activity_game` layout?

Comment: @abest Thanks for the link and explanation, that explains the error. I'm feeling like I'd rather avoid this then and go more for my second idea, but if I can't figure that out I'll try modifying the view per the documentation you linked so that it appears properly. Sure I will post it in a second.

Comment: I have the same problem and I cannot manage to find a solution even though I've been spending the last day searching on the Internet. Can you please tell me how did you manage to fix it?